# Convert Object to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I want to convert an object similar to this:

```
    {
    "team1": {
        "test123": [{
            "players":"3",
            "city":"blabla"
            "date": null,
            "country": "NZ",
        }, {
            "players":"7",
            "city":"blabla2"
            "date": null,
            "country": "US",
        }]
    }
}
```

and to receive an array that will contain -> for an object the key and for array it will concat the values of the array.
For example:

```
["team1","test123",[{
                "players":"3",
                "city":"blabla"
                "date": null,
                "country": "NZ",
            }, {
                "players":"7",
                "city":"blabla2"
                "date": null,
                "country": "US",
            }]]
```

I tried to run with recursion over the array but It didn't work.

*my object might be much bigger and dipper + unknown labels

Tried something like this but didn't work:

```
function rec(obj) {
  var res = [];
  for(var key in obj) {
     if (angular.isArray(obj[key])){
        res.concat(obj[key]);
     } 
     else {
        rec(obj[key]);
        res.push(key);
     }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: There's many ways to do this. Please be specific, include the code you currently have, and tell us where the problem is.

Comment: @Jeroen edited my question

Comment: `key` is a property name. Why are you checking it to be an array? `angular.isArray(key) //nonsense`

Comment: the value of `test123` remains intact?

Comment: @NinaScholz no, all values and labels can be different I cannot know exactly how will me object will look like.

Comment: Why in Cthulhu's name would you even want this?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko sorry I just typed what I did in the question ( I edited my question)

Comment: @Jonathan I wish I didn't! Is this so complicate?

Comment: why did I got -1 on this?

Comment: @lili it's as easy as it is silly...

Comment: The array `res` will have to be part of the recursion right? Either as an argument or at least concatenated with the recursive call `rec(obj[key])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why would you need this, but this will reproduce the result you have provided. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/00zohbnf/).

```
function weirdestFlatternEver(obj) {
    var res = [], name, value;
  for(name in obj) {
    value = obj[name];
    res.push(name);
    if(Array.isArray(value)) {
        res.push(value);
    }
    else {
        res.push.apply(res, weirdestFlatternEver(value));
    }

  }
  return res;
}
```